# Hitting a snag with a Sub and multiple Functions. Attempting to make it a one button push action

Tags: excel, vba

The code has been updated, and I am getting an error, even after checking Microsoft Scripting RunTime off to be active. Below is the error:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update_JL()

    Dim wsJL As Worksheet 'Jobs List
    Dim wsJD As Worksheet 'Jobs Data
    Dim wsJAR As Worksheet 'JL Archive
    Dim lastrow As Long, fstcell As Long
    Dim strCompany As String, strPart As String, strPath As String

    Set wsJL = Sheets("Jobs List")
    Set wsJD = Sheets("Jobs Data")
    Set wsJAR = Sheets("JL Archive")

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Intersect(wsJL.UsedRange, wsJL.Columns("Q"))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Same"
        With Intersect(.Offset(2).EntireRow, .Parent.Range("B:O"))
            .Copy wsJAR.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    With wsJD
        'Clean empty cells in Column C
        lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Range("C5:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    With Intersect(wsJD.UsedRange, wsJD.Columns("Q"))
        ActiveSheet.Range("P:Q").Calculate
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Different"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    With wsJD
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("G")).Cut .Range("F1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("H")).Cut .Range("G1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("L")).Cut .Range("H1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("N")).Cut .Range("I1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("B:I")).Copy wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With

        With wsJL
        lastrow = wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        wsJL.Range("R1:Y1").Copy
        wsJL.Range("B3:I" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        lastrow = wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        fstcell = wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        wsJL.Range("Z1:AG1").Copy wsJL.Range("J" & fstcell & ":Q" & lastrow)
        wsJL.Range("S2:X2").Copy wsJL.Range("P" & fstcell & ":T" & lastrow)
        lastrow = wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        wsJL.Range("J:Q").Calculate
        Range("B3:N" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("F3" & lastrow), order1:=xlAscending

    End With

    With wsJAR
        lastrow = wsJAR.Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
        wsJAR.Range("R2:T2").Copy wsJAR.Range("R3:T" & lastrow)
        wsJAR.Range("M1").Copy wsJAR.Range("M3:M" & lastrow)
    End With

    With wsJL
        strCompany = Range("C3") ' assumes company name in C3
        strPart = CleanName(Range("D3")) ' assumes part in D1
        strPath = CleanName(Range("Lists!$G$2"))

        If Not FolderExists(strPath & strCompany) Then
        'company doesn't exist, so create full path
            FolderCreate strPath & strCompany & Application.PathSeparator & strPart
        Else
        'company does exist, but does part folder
            If Not FolderExists(strPath & strCompany & Application.PathSeparator & strPart) Then
                FolderCreate strPath & strCompany & Application.PathSeparator & strPart
            End If
        End If

        Range("J:M").Calculate
    End With

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub

Function FolderCreate(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderCreate = True
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If Functions.FolderExists(path) Then
    Exit Function
Else
    On Error GoTo DeadInTheWater
    fso.CreateFolder path ' could there be any error with this, like if the path is really screwed up?
    Exit Function
End If

DeadInTheWater:
    MsgBox "A folder could not be created for the following path: " & path & ". Check the path name and try again."
    FolderCreate = False
    Exit Function

End Function

Function FolderExists(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderExists = False
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If fso.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExists = True

End Function

Function CleanName(strName As String) As String
'will clean part # name so it can be made into valid folder name
'may need to add more lines to get rid of other characters

    CleanName = Replace(strName, "/", "")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "*", "")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, ".", "")

End Function
```

The error is here so far, for this is as far as the script has allowed me to go. The error is:

```
Compile Error: Variable not defined
```

The code is below, the place of contention is here between the `*`. `If **Functions**.FolderExists(path) Then`

```
Function FolderCreate(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderCreate = True
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If Functions.FolderExists(path) Then
    Exit Function
Else
    On Error GoTo DeadInTheWater
    fso.CreateFolder path ' could there be any error with this, like if the path is really screwed up?
    Exit Function
End If

DeadInTheWater:
    MsgBox "A folder could not be created for the following path: " & path & ". Check the path name and try again."
    FolderCreate = False
    Exit Function

End Function
```

Comment: why does it need to be one sub? splitting things into sections helps readability. If subs or functions need to be called one after the other, then set up a main routine to call them

Comment: The reason is because this needs to be a one button push concept. That's why. I don't have the ability to adjust this to make it be a multi-button option.

Comment: You don't need more than one button. What Sean is suggesting is to create a main routine that does nothing but call the other subs. Your button will call the main routine.

Comment: Look at the code in this answer for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10779424/138938 DispatchTotalsByPNNumber is a sub that calls the others.

Comment: It's not so much about calling different. I fixed the OP's original integration of the function I built in my answer below, where he misunderstood how to integrate the function calls I made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just had the code a little off.

each new function should go below the sub, as it is a separate procedure that gets called from the sub. Worth reading up on functions and sub and calling them from one another.

I've reorganized below. Hopefully, will be a little more clear and clean.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Update_JL()

    Dim wsJL As Worksheet 'Jobs List
    Dim wsJD As Worksheet 'Jobs Data
    Dim wsJAR As Worksheet 'JL Archive
    Dim lastrow As Long, fstcell As Long
    Dim strCompany As String, strPart As String, strPath As String

    Set wsJL = Sheets("Jobs List")
    Set wsJD = Sheets("Jobs Data")
    Set wsJAR = Sheets("JL Archive")

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .DisplayAlerts = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    With Intersect(wsJL.UsedRange, wsJL.Columns("Q"))
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Same"
        With Intersect(.Offset(2).EntireRow, .Parent.Range("B:O"))
            .Copy wsJAR.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            .EntireRow.Delete
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With

    With wsJD
        'Clean up step 1
        lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        Range("C5:C" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

        'Blow away rows that are useless
        lastrow = Range("B5").End(xlDown).Row
        Range("P5:Q5").Copy wsJD.Range("P6:Q" & lastrow)
        wsJD.UsedRange.Copy Sheets.Add.Range("A1")
    End With

    With Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, ActiveSheet.Columns("Q"))
        ActiveSheet.Range("P:Q").Calculate
        .AutoFilter 1, "<>Different"
        .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow.Delete
    End With

    With ActiveSheet
        ActiveSheet.Range("P:Q").Calculate
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("G")).Cut .Range("F1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("H")).Cut .Range("G1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("L")).Cut .Range("H1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Columns("N")).Cut .Range("I1")
        Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("B:I")).Copy wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        .Delete
    End With

    With wsJL
        lastrow = wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        wsJL.Range("R1:Y1").Copy
        wsJL.Range("B3:I" & lastrow).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
        lastrow = wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "J").End(xlUp).Row + 1
        fstcell = wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
        wsJL.Range("Z1:AG1").Copy wsJL.Range("J" & fstcell & ":Q" & lastrow)
        wsJL.Range("S2:X2").Copy wsJL.Range("P" & fstcell & ":T" & lastrow)
        lastrow = wsJL.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        wsJL.Range("J:Q").Calculate
        Range("B3:N" & lastrow).Sort key1:=Range("F3" & lastrow), order1:=xlAscending

    End With

    With wsJAR
        lastrow = wsJAR.Cells(Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row
        wsJAR.Range("R2:T2").Copy wsJAR.Range("R3:T" & lastrow)
        wsJAR.Range("M1").Copy wsJAR.Range("M3:M" & lastrow)
    End With

    With wsJL

        strCompany = Range("C3") ' assumes company name in C3
        strPart = CleanName(Range("D3")) ' assumes part in D1
        strPath = CleanName(Range("Lists!$G$2"))

        If Not FolderExists(strPath & strCompany) Then
        'company doesn't exist, so create full path
            FolderCreate strPath & strCompany & Application.PathSeparator & strPart
        Else
        'company does exist, but does part folder
            If Not FolderExists(strPath & strCompany & Application.PathSeparator & strPart) Then
                FolderCreate strPath & strCompany & Application.PathSeparator & strPart
            End If
        End If

        Range("J:M").Calculate

    End With


    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .DisplayAlerts = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

End Sub

Function FolderCreate(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderCreate = True
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If FolderExists(path) Then
    Exit Function
Else
    On Error GoTo DeadInTheWater
    fso.CreateFolder path ' could there be any error with this, like if the path is really screwed up?
    Exit Function
End If

DeadInTheWater:
    MsgBox "A folder could not be created for the following path: " & path & ". Check the path name and try again."
    FolderCreate = False
    Exit Function

End Function

Function FolderExists(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderExists = False
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If fso.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExists = True

End Function

Function CleanName(strName As String) As String
'will clean part # name so it can be made into valid folder name
'may need to add more lines to get rid of other characters

    CleanName = Replace(strName, "/", "")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, "*", "")
    CleanName = Replace(CleanName, ".", "")

End Function
```

Comment: code could also be cleaned up a bit more for readability purposes, just so you know. I edited with a little cleanup, but I left all the ActiveSheet stuff alone, since I have no idea what the ActiveSheet will be...

Comment: The Active Sheet would be the "new sheet" created from here `UsedRange.Copy Sheets.Add.Range("A1")` it has no name, just a new sheet. So that's why it didn't have a name, except ActiveSheet. I'll take what you did a look and enter it once I'm done with another problem I ran into. I had to move things around after adding in another issue I was working on here with, and it seems the code works, but I tend to run into an organization bug that shouldn't be.

Thanks again :)

Comment: look how i organized the above and it will help you understand how methods and procedures need to be organized and kept together (like With -> End With and such) It should help clear things up.

Comment: I was actually going over my old scripts and this one as well and decided to re-write the script from scratch. I've removed the ActiveSheet and decided to clean up a lot. I'll post a revision after I'm done.

Comment: Ok, before I post, I got an error on the script you gave me. `Function FolderExists(ByVal path As String) As Boolean

FolderExists = False
Dim fso As New FileSystemObject

If fso.FolderExists(path) Then FolderExists = True

End Function`

The error is a Compile error: User-defined type not defined. This `fso As New FileSystemObject` was highlighted.

Comment: As I wrote in the top comment line of the code, you need to set a reference to Microsoft Scripting RunTime in the VBE under Tools > References.

Comment: Ok, got an error, even after everything is cleaned up. Fixing the OP to show.

Comment: just delete "Functions." I did that in my one of my edits, or at least i thought i did

Comment: That "Functions." was a module from the code I used to copy from. I just forgot to delete it out, when I pasted it for your use :)

Comment: Do I need to add a Dimm for the FolderExists function though? I only ask because it seems to be required for to know if the folder exists or not...or am I wrong?

Comment: Ok, still asking, do I need the FolderExists function? Because it seems to me that the function is important? Yes?

Comment: You do not need a Dim for the Subs or Functions themselves, you only need to dimension variables used within subs for functions. Yes, you do need the FolderExists function to use this code. You could write the code a different way and not use it, but as is, you do need it.

Comment: I just updated the original question, I have been working on another line of thought. Could you review and tell me what you think?

Comment: Sorry ... I tend to think on the fly. I'll do what you asked though. I hate re-posting the same question with a different twist to it, because it seems to me that I'm asking the same thing over, and over and over again without really not accepting answers, even though I am.

Comment: Right, but the point is that you got the information you needed (or maybe you didn't) for the original question posted. So, now when someone has a similar problem they can find a viable solution. With programming, it's very detailed, and each line of code or batch of lines, could potentially have it's own type of question. For you, I'd also recommend reading a book on VBA and the excel object model.  You obviously have programming skills, but I think reading up on that stuff will help you understand things tremendously better... at least it did me.