# Merge duplicate cell values and their sums in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, merge, duplicates

I am trying to merge duplicate cell values in Excel using VBA.
Here is an example of the data:

> Col1 Col2
>   run   1
>   run   2
>   see   9
>   go    5
>   see   1

I need to merge this information so that the data is as follows:

> Col1 Col2
>   run   3
>   see   10
>   go    5

Meaning, that I need to merge the duplicate values in Column 1 and sum their corresponding values in Column 2.

I have already consulted and tried a similar situation here: [How to SUM / merge similar rows in Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409738/how-to-sum-merge-similar-rows-in-excel-using-vba?rq=1)

Where one of the recommendations was the following macro:

```
Sub Macro1()
Dim ColumnsCount As Integer

ColumnsCount = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Columns.Count

ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Activate


Do While ActiveCell.Row <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        For i = 1 To ColumnsCount - 1
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value + ActiveCell.Offset(1, i).Value
        Next
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Loop
End Sub
```

However, it seems to be creating an infinite loop that causes my excel to crash, without actually merging anything.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can adapt this code to arrive at the merge solution that I need?

Comment: If it were me and I had to do this in-place with VBA (as opposed to using a pivot table or `SUMIF` formulae) then I would sort the data by column 1 and then work upwards merging from the last row to the first; it'll give you much tidier code. Can provide example if you wish. EDIT: Sorry just realised you might want to keep the col 1 values in their original order of appearance which would complicate things slightly but not much.

Comment: An example would be extremely appreciated. Thank you. PS: the order of the Col1 values is not of importance (can deal with that after), as much as summing their corresponding values in Col2.

Comment: I've given a VBA answer below, but I think you'd be better off usingh an [Array Formula with SUMIF](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/ArrayFormulas.aspx)

Comment: a pivot table would seem to be the easiest way to organize this data

Comment: You could also do this using SubTotals function in Excels Data menu

Comment: ye one more method might be: [Summarize data using SUMPRODUCT](http://exceluser.com/explore/summaries.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following assumes your table starts in cell A1 and columns C onwards are empty (if they are not you will lose data on the merged rows)

```
Sub mergeCategoryValues()
Dim lngRow As Long

With ActiveSheet

    lngRow = .Cells(.LastCell.Row, 1).End(xlUp).Row

    .Cells(1).CurrentRegion.Sort key1:=.Cells(1), header:=xlNo 'change this to xlYes if your table has header cells

    Do

        If .Cells(lngRow - 1, 1) = .Cells(lngRow, 1) Then
            .Cells(lngRow - 1, 2) = .Cells(lngRow - 1, 2) + .Cells(lngRow, 2)
            .Rows(lngRow).Delete
        End If

        lngRow = lngRow - 1

    Loop Until lngRow < 2

End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

try this (sorting first, then running your code):

```
Sub Merge()

Dim ColumnsCount As Integer
Dim i As Integer

Range("A1").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlGuess, _
    OrderCustom:=1, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal

Do While ActiveCell.Row <= ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
    If ActiveCell.Value = ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Value Then
        For i = 1 To ColumnsCount - 1
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value = ActiveCell.Offset(0, i).Value +     ActiveCell.Offset(1, i).Value
        Next
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).EntireRow.Delete shift:=xlShiftUp
    Else
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If
Loop

End Sub
```