# How to merge and sum using excel vba

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

Im trying to create vba to merge the text value and sum the amount.
For example I have below data

```
Date         Name            Type       Amount
1 Jan        Test1            A           100
1 Jan        Test1            A           150
2 Jan        Test1            A           110
2 Jan        Test1            A           200
1 Jan        Test1            B           130
1 Jan        Test1            B           110
1 Jan        Test2            B           130
1 Jan        Test2            B           160
1 Jan        Test3            B           180
```

The result should look like this

```
Date         Name            Type       Amount
1 Jan        Test1            A           250
2 Jan        Test1            A           310
1 Jan        Test1            B           240
1 Jan        Test2            B           290
1 Jan        Test3            B           180
```

I have try to use below vba but does not seem to work
[How to SUM / merge similar rows in Excel using VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6409738/how-to-sum-merge-similar-rows-in-excel-using-vba)

Comment: why use vba if built-in features will be better?  also you need to include code indicating what you tried and what doesn't work

Comment: @Ray I suggest you use a PivotTable. Google will tell you everything you need to know about how to set them up, and how to use them.

Comment: I have tried using pivot but i cant get the exact result. And I also need to automate it.

Comment: A pivot table is semi-automatic. All you need to do afterwards is to right-click the pivot-table and select "refresh". If that's not sufficiently automated or you need another method then you can also consider using [PowerQuery M](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/query-bi/m/power-query-m-reference). If you want to automate the "refresh" process then you can do so using VBA (with macro recorder). If this still doesn't provide the desired outcome then please elaborate.

Comment: @Ray, just record a macro whilst doing the following: 1. copy the columns Date, Name and Type into a new column range, and remove duplicates over them. Then in the column to the right enter a sumifs() formula and drag it down by double clicking on the crosshairs. That should give you a pretty decent idea where to start writing your VBA.

Answer (score 0):

How about the following, this will give you the desired result by using a SumIf formula then replacing values in column D and removing duplicates:

```
Sub foo()
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")
'declare and set your worksheet, amend as required
LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
'get the last row with data on Column A

ws.Range("E2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUMIFS(C[-1],C[-4],RC[-4],C[-3],RC[-3],C[-2],RC[-2])"
'add the sumif formula
ws.Range("E2").AutoFill Destination:=Range("E2:E" & LastRow), Type:=xlFillDefault
'fill the formula down to last cell
ws.Columns("E:E").Copy
ws.Columns("E:E").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
'copy and paste as values
ws.Range("D2:D" & LastRow).Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
'remove column D's values and bring values from Column E into it
ws.Range("$A$1:$G$" & LastRow).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7), Header:=xlNo
'remove duplicates
End Sub
```